# Research on SDR security Gnu Radio and legal transmission with filters

Tags: filters, lowpass-filter, gnuradio, software-defined-radio

In fact, I am doing research around SDR and possible dangers. Then I stumbled upon the most well known "replay attack". Via Black hills, I came across the following diagram in gnuradio:
[image]

The lower part (so not greyed out) is for transmit signals. Because I want to do this legally and as safely as possible without harmonics, I was wondering what filter I should use and its values?

I suspect this filter will also come between the "File Source" and the two output blocks? Thanks in advance for your help! I use a hackrf one with an ant500 antenna and as software gnu radio because here is the possibility for filters.

Comment: Regulations vary by country. The safest approach is to consult a lawyer, but you should at least look up the relevant regulations, which are usually published by a government agency (e.g. the FCC in the US).

Comment: also, since you're just starting out with GNU Radio: your installation of GNU Radio is very old, the screenshot you're showing is of an End-of-Life GNU Radio 3.7. I don't even know many still-active operating systems where the default means of installation of GNU Radio would give you a GNU Radio this old!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for reaction but as said: "Via Black hills, I came across the following diagram in gnuradio:"... So this is not a screenshot from my software version.

Comment: OK, that's great to hear :)